# Global Hyperbolicity and Timelike Boundary

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, causality, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

I am trying to understand and show that **asymptotically Anti-de Sitter** spacetimes are **not globally hyperbolic**.

Now, I have found papers that talk about global hyperbolic spacetimes with timelike boundary. This startles me. My understanding was that the existence of a timelike boundary precludes global hyperbolicity because...

1. ... a Cauchy surface may only intersect the timelike boundary at one point, since two points on the timelike boundary may precede one another and so cannot be part of the same Cauchy surface.
2. ... timelike boundary also means, that it can be reached by timelike curves (or doesn't it?), so I guess one could find a curve that escapes through the boundary but does not intersect the Cauchy surface (which means it actually is no Cauchy surface, and therefore the spacetime is not globally hyperbolic).

If my understanding is wrong, however, (which I suppose it is), how would one then show non-global hyperbolicity of asymptotically AdS spacetime, if one cannot use the mere fact that a timelike boundary exists?